# Change the font size of the Section Name on a Collapsible Section

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, modern-pages, sitepages

I have created a collapsible section, and I want to change the font size of the Section Name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no SharePoint default settings available to change the font size of the collapsible section display name.

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/) - check comments section.

[image]

If you want Microsoft to provide such options, you can add new feedback/idea at: [SharePoint Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) **OR**

Vote on existing relevant ideas from: [Search - Collapsible section font size](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/search/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472?q=collapsible+section+font+size).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ganesh Sanap, SharePoint Online does not provide default settings to customize the font size, font family, or font color of collapsible section titles.

So, you cannot change the font size, font family or font color of the section display name.

Source: [SharePoint: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/)

I found a thread similar to your needs, please refer to it:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1340891/i-want-to-increase-the-section-font-size-in-sharep

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.